# Physical Size of a Naked Singularity

Tags: black-holes, event-horizon, singularities

I have watched a few videos about naked singularities, and it is my understanding that one is a singularity without an event horizon.  My question, is could you ever have that with anything larger than a Planck mass black hole?

Answer (score 2):

A singularity means a breakdown in the metric, which is the apparatus used for measurement. Therefore its size is undefined.